Confusion about the geometric product and how things commute when distributing and reducing.
I am am a beginner to geometric algebra and I am trying to understand how the geometric product works for multivectors but I get tripped up somewhere when I try to do the calculations.
Here is a simple example. Given a multivector that contains a scalar and one basis vector, I try to multiply it with itself.
$$V = (2+3e_1)$$
If I do it using the outer and inner product
$$VV = V \cdot V + V \wedge V$$
The outer product gives
$$V \cdot V = 2*2 + 3*3 = 13$$
And any vectors outer product with itself is always zero
$$V \wedge V = 0$$
Which gives
$$VV = 13$$
And this makes sense to me, this is what I expect to get.
However when I try to distribute and then reduce knowing that $e_1e_1=1$
$$V = (2+3e_1)(2+3e_1)$$
I distribute to this
$$V = 2*2 + 2*3e_1 + 3e_1*2 + 3e_1*3e_1$$
Then assuming scalars and basis vectors commute I get this
$$2*2=4$$
$$3e_1*3e_1 = 3e_1*e_13 = 3*3=9$$
Which makes sense, however since i assumed scalars and basis vectors commute i should be able to swap like this
$$2*3e_1 + 3e_1*2 = 2*3e_1 + 2*3e_1 = 12e_1$$
Which would mean that
$$VV = 13 + 12e_1$$
But I expect it to be zero since the outer product is zero
$$2*3e_1 + 3e_1*2=0$$
Which would require it to anti commute like this
$$2*3e_1 = -3e_1*2$$
But that make this part incorrect instead
$$3e_1*3e_1 = (3e_1)*(-e_13) = 3*-3=-9$$
And would result in
$$VV = -5$$
It seems I misunderstand something about how it commutes and that is where I mess up but I am unsure.

Be careful, for example, when you say every vector's outer product with itself vanishes, since your $V$ is not a pure vector.

In my books, with its inner product, a correct statement for a vector $v$ and any multivector $W$, is $vW = v \cdot W + v \wedge W$, but

I got cut off in my comment. ... but $Wv = W \cdot v +  W \wedge v$ is not. The paper \emph{The inner products of geometric algebra} explains this: https://www.researchgate.net/publication/2842332_The_Inner_Products_of_Geometric_Algebra

$AB = A\cdot B + A\wedge B$ is false in general. When you see it stated in introductions to geometric algebra, $A$ and $B$ are usually assumed to be vectors. More generally it is true as long as at least one of them is a vectors and you interpret $\cdot$ as a contraction.
Is also false that $A\wedge A=0$. This is only guaranteed when $A$ is a vector. Similarly, it is false in general that the wedge product is anticommutative.
The correct value of $VV$ is the second one you gave, $VV = 13 + 12e_1$.
